# How to parse a string that looks like JSON with lots of embedded classes in python?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a string that lists the properties of a request event.

My string looks like:

```
requestBody: {
    propertyA = 1
    propertyB = 2
    propertyC = {
        propertyC1 = 1
        propertyC2 = 2
    }
    propertyD = [
        { propertyD1 = { propertyD11 = 1}},
        { propertyD1 = [ {propertyD21 = 1, propertyD22 = 2}, 
                         {propertyD21 = 3, propertyD22 = 4}]}
    ]
}
```

I have tried to replace the `"="` with `":"` so that I can put it into a JSON reader in python, but JSON also requires that key and value are stored in string with double quotes and a `","` to separate each KV pair. This then became a little complicated to implement. What are some better approaches to parsing this into **python dictionary** with exactly the same structure (e.g. embedded dictionaries are also preserved)?

Question:
If I were to write a full parser, what's the main pattern that I should tackle? Storing parenthesis in a stack until the parenthesis completes?

Comment: It appears consistently defined. Write a full parser from scratch?

Comment: I understand defining multiple properties inside `{}`'s as some sort of nested object (such as `propertyC`), and I understand multiple objects inside `[]`'s as an array of objects (as in `propertyD2`). But what is intended when you have multiple properties inside []'s (as in `propertyD`)? Should this really be an object in {}'s, with properties `propertyD1` and `propertyD2`?

Comment: Also, it appears that sometimes list elements are comma-delimited, and sometimes newline-delimited. For instance, is there supposed to be a comma after the definition of `propertyA`?

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I revised my string format a little. For your first question, objects are always enclosed by {}, arrays should only contain objects enclosed by {}. For your second question, yes, there is inconsistency in comma-delimited and newline-delimited records in object (however, arrays are always comma-delimited).

Comment: What software is generating these strings?  There may be a Python module for working with it already.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice case for using pyparsing, especially since it adds the issue of recursive structuring.

The short answer is the following parser (processes everything after the leading `requestBody :`):

```
LBRACE,RBRACE,LBRACK,RBRACK,EQ = map(Suppress, "{}[]=")
NL = LineEnd().setName("NL")

# define special delimiter for lists and objects, since they can be
# comma-separated or just newline-separated
list_delim = NL | ','
list_delim.leaveWhitespace()

# use a parse action to convert numeric values to ints or floats at parse time
def convert_number(t):
    try:
        return int(t[0])
    except ValueError:
        return float(t[0])
number = Word(nums, nums+'.').addParseAction(convert_number)

qs = quotedString

# forward-declare value, since it will be defined recursively
obj_value = Forward()

ident = Word(alphas, alphanums+'_')
obj_property = Group(ident + EQ + obj_value)

# use Dict wrapper to auto-define nested properties as key-values
obj = Group(LBRACE + Dict(Optional(delimitedList(obj_property, delim=list_delim))) + RBRACE)

obj_array = Group(LBRACK + Optional(delimitedList(obj, delim=list_delim)) + RBRACK)

# now assign to previously-declared obj_value, using '<<=' operator
obj_value <<= obj_array | obj | number | qs

# parse the data
res = obj.parseString(sample)[0]

# convert the result to a dict
import pprint
pprint.pprint(res.asDict())
```

gives

```
{'propertyA': 1,
 'propertyB': 2,
 'propertyC': {'propertyC1': 1, 'propertyC2': 2},
 'propertyD': {'propertyD1': {'propertyD11': 1},
               'propertyD2': {'propertyD21': 3, 'propertyD22': 4}}}
```

Comment: can you briefly explain what `obj_value <<= obj_array | obj | number | qs` does?

Comment: We have to use the `<<=` operator to assign expressions to a Forward expression. You will see this in most recursive pyparsing programs. In your case, `obj_value` was defined as a Forward as a sort of placeholder, as if to say, "I'll define this later, but I need a reference for this expression." Then `obj_value` gets used in `obj_property`, which is part of `obj`.  Ultimately, we want to define just what goes into `obj_value`, which is any one of an `obj_array`, an `obj`, a number, or a quoted string. Since `obj_value` is already defined as a Forward, we assign this using the `<<=` operator.